# Finding canonical posts for closing endlessly asked questions as duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, search, canonical

I am active on SO, mostly on iOS questions.

There is a glut of questions that occur over and over and over, e.g., variations on the "How do I send a value from one UIViewController to another?"

Lots of people flag these as duplicates.

Is there a tool on SO that lets you readily find a good, canonical question and answer that addresses the endlessly asked question? Or can other readers suggest a method for finding an appropriate example of the duplicate question to cite?

I find the search tool in SO to be hit-or-miss at best.

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252234/456814) for how to use Google more effectively. Also, [this](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en). **Also, can we just replace [main]'s built-in Elastic Search with Google search results already?** I rarely ever use the built-in search `:P` **Somebody make that into a feature request please!**

Comment: Update: [I just made the feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254093/456814).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree that Stack Overflow's search tool isn't very helpful in finding relevant results. I usually just use Google with some extra search parameters like `site:`. For example:

> "foo in the bar <some language> site:stackoverflow.com"

Narrow down your search as needed. That works for me most of the time.

Another trick is post the question title into the [Ask Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) title field. That search works better than the site-wide search, in my opinion. The "Related" list in the sidebar is also helpful.

Comment: Cool. I did not know about the site: qualifier for Google. That's perfect. It lets me use the power of Google's fuzzy logic search engine to find what I'm looking for. (voted)

Comment: @DuncanC: There is also `allintext`, `allintitle`, `inurl` etc. I also use [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com) when searching for specific programming syntax (Google ignore most punctuation).

Comment: Where is that stuff documented? I spent a little time trying to figure out how to search for constructs with symbols in them and failed.

Comment: @DuncanC: [This guide](http://www.googleguide.com/using_advanced_operators.html) is helpful. If you're talking about SymbolHound, there's [this post](http://stackapps.com/q/2690/21711) on Stack Apps, but I'm not sure if it has a documentation of any sorts.

Comment: you can also do "Settings" -> "Advanced search"

Answer (score 9):

If I know I've seen a question 1000 times before, sometimes I find the original by going to the tag page and clicking the [frequent tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=frequent&pageSize=50).  This is a collection of questions that have the most "closed as duplicate" questions linking to them.

Comment: That's also a good tip. I've tried creating a new question and feeding in a version of the "asked 1000 times" question, but that doesn't work very well. For the questions that are asked over and over and over, they do tend to be in the to 20 or so questions in the frequent list. Thanks for that. (voted)

Answer (score 4):

If it is being asked over and over, it would make sense to add a canonical answer to the tag wiki (see for example the bottom of the [java tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)) in a list of FAQs.

Next time you look for a canonical answer, you can search the wiki and find it there.