# Include the "Has Accepted Answer" shading in the Related sidebar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accepted-answer, related-questions

When I am reading/writing/answering a question, the "Related" sidebar next to the question includes links to questions that, through some arcane magic, have been identified as similar to the question I'm currently looking at.

[image: Related Sidebar]

This is helpful on many levels:

1. When asking a question, it can [point me towards questions that might already have my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254064/find-duplicate-question/254068#254068) that didn't come up in earlier searches.
2. When searching for an answer, it can help me find questions similar to the one I'm looking at, which may actually be better than the one I currently have open.
3. When answering a question, it can point me towards older, better answers or even help me find other questions I might be capable of answering.

In all of these uses, it would be helpful to know if the linked question has an accepted answer or not.  Currently, the Review sidebar shows the points given to the question itself, but does not indicate whether that question has been resolved.

My user profile has a list of the questions I have asked, with a similar number counter for votes.  Unlike the Related sidebar, though, it has green shading to indicate whether an answer to that question has been accepted.

[image: My Questions]

Same basic data, but this time it has beautiful green shading and yellow font to show me that it's already got an accepted answer. I think that same functionality might also be helpful to have in the Related sidebar.

**SUGGESTION:** can the Related sidebar be edited to indicate whether the question has an accepted answer?

edit: it appears this idea [has been mentioned at least once before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252985/information-of-related-questions)

edit again: it also appears that this feature already works on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments)

[image: This is making me jealous]

Comment: This is already done on other SE sites. Why not on SO ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been implemented as a side effect of the [great CSS unification of 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321419).

[image: related]